# jquery trigger: how can I use it to trigger a link when the page is loaded

Tags: jquery, triggers, click, event-triggers

How can I use `trigger()` to trigger the click event on a particular link only?

for instance, I have this menu,

```
<li><a href="#" class="load-popup-public 500x400">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="load-popup-public 500x400">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="load-popup-public 500x400">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="load-popup-public 500x400">4</a></li>
```

and I want to trigger the first link only when the page is loaded. so that I can call this function automatically when the page is loaded,

```
$('.load-popup-public').click(function (){
...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:first` selector to select the first link and then use document `ready` event.

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.load-popup-public').click(function (){
   //Some code here
  });
 $(".load-popup-public:first").trigger("click");
})
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zeyWN/

Comment: thanks so much! this is the answer I am looking for! not `ready`! thanks :-)

Comment: @lauthiamkok, this DOES use the .ready function. $(function(){}) is the same as $(document).ready(){}

Comment: @James: The question is about how to get hold of first anchor element in the collection not how to use ready event?

Comment: @Cybernate, there's no question that your answer was the best (I neglected to add the :first selector), I just wanted+ the OP to understand that he did in fact use .ready to execute this when the page loads (one of his initial requests). +1

Answer (score 0):

You can include this function in the .ready of jquery:

http://api.jquery.com/ready/